# "Uploading custom apps is not allowed" When Installing Microsoft Teams Sample App

Tags: microsoft-teams

**Update:** I just realized that I can install it if I download it and then bring it in via Apps > Upload a custom app, so it's only installing it from within App Studio that gives the error.

---

I'm trying to work through the sample app at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-dotnet-app-studio, but I'm stuck at the part where you install it into Teams.

I get the error: "Uploading custom apps is not allowed."

According to [Prepare your Office 365 tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-tenant), in the admin center, under Settings > Services & add-ins > Microsoft Teams > Tenant-wide settings > Apps, I should turn on "Allow sideloading of external apps." In my tenant, that is indeed turned off:
[image]

But I can't turn it on. It's disabled, saying the settings have moved to the "Microsoft Teams & Skype for Business admin center."

In that admin center, I went to Teams apps > Permission policies. There, for "Global (Org-wide default), I have "allow all apps" for everything:
[image].

For "Org-wide app settings", I have interaction with custom apps turned on:
[image].

Under Setup policies > Global (Org-wide default), I have "Allow uploading custom apps" on:
[image].

And I'm signed in as a user governed by that policy:
[image]

I'm stumped. What else do I need to do so that I can sideload a Teams app for development?

Comment: We are looking into this. Do you see Upload a custom app for admin user or a normal user? Could you please check this in 24 hours if you are able to see Upload a custom app for normal user?

Comment: Any luck? I am also struck with same issue as of now.

Comment: Your update #1 above worked. I downloaded from App studio and uploaded it thru normal user and it worked. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I'm having same problem. Even though enabled custom app upload and added the policy.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it actually made me crazy especially because it may take a few hours to apply changes. Finally I was able to resolve the problem in the following way. I can imagine that certain steps are unnecessary but who knows.

1. By following instructions in the [Manage app setup policies in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-custom-app-policies-and-settings), enable "Upload custom apps" in "Global (Org-wide default)".
2. Following same instructions created a custom setup policy with enabled "Upload custom apps".
3. Enable all permissions in "Global (Org-wide default)" as described in the [Manage app permission policies in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-permission-policies)
4. Create a new permission policy with everything enabled.
5. Wait about an hour.
6. Assign these new policies to the user.
7. Make sure that everything what is mentioned in [Manage custom app policies and settings in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-custom-app-policies-and-settings) is enabled.
8. Wait another hour.
9. Quit desktop application, and start it again.

Now, finally, it works.

Comment: Very efficient! Thanks MSFT!